# Question about countable additivity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am learning measure theory, and I encountered to prove finite additivity from countable additivity, this site partially solved my question.

@MISC {10153,
TITLE = {Finite additivity follows from countable additivity!},
AUTHOR = {user17762},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10153 (version: 2010-11-13)},
EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10153},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10153}
}

However, I found this equation confusing.

$\sum_{1}^{n}\mu(E_i)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i)$, If $\forall i,\mu(E_i) < \infty$, this equation is right, the right-hand side is a series and its finite summation is  $\sum_{1}^{n}\mu(E_i)$, so it has a limit. But if there exists some $i$ such that $\mu(E_i)=\infty$, what is the meaning of RHS since I have not learned how to add infinity in series?

Comment: $\infty+x$ is defined to be $\infty$ for any $x$.  (In general, doing addition with $\infty$ can be problematic if there are both positive and negative terms, but when everything is nonnegative it works fine.)

Comment: First, by the definition you gave above, we have the finite summation  $\sum_{1}^{n}\mu(E_i)=\infty$, so what is the meaning of infinite summation?

Comment: Second, can you give me an example regarding the line I quote'In general, doing addition with ∞ can be problematic if there are both positive and negative terms'